# Hive Split and Total

Tags: sql, hive

So, say I want to count the amount of 'Class1' entries across 2 columns... each input in the columns are a string.

say I have input data of :

```
column_1                    column_2
Class1;full;11;11           Class1;full;11;11
Class2;limited;11;11        Class1;full;11;11
```

Desired Output:

```
   Class        Total
    Class1      3
    Class2      1
```

Actual Output:

```
   Class        Total
    Class1      2
```

However, It looks like the split function only assess the final column.

Below is my Query...

```
SELECT  Class,COUNT(*) AS Total

FROM (SELECT ID 

        ,SPLIT(CLASS_LIST1,'\u0059')[0]
        ,SPLIT(CLASS_LIST2,'\u0059')[0]


            AS Class

FROM table

    )a

group by class
```

Any ideas on how to get the total of both columns?

Comment: You are not even selecting first column, it is not aliased. You are selecting only second column which is aliased `Class` in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT  Class,COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM (SELECT ID, SPLIT(CLASS_LIST1,'\073')[0] AS Class FROM table
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ID, SPLIT(CLASS_LIST2,'\073')[0] AS Class FROM table
    )a
group by class
```